# real-valued measurable function under a transformation.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Here's the question:  "Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Show that $f(ax)$ is measurable for all real $a$."

I know we can to look at sets of the form $\{f \geq \alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ is any real number. Yet, I'm not sure what this information gives us about the function $f(ax)$. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?  Any hints are very appreciated!

Comment: What about the composition of measurable functions?

Comment: I don't believe the composition of measurable functions is necessarily measurable.

Comment: But it is, and it's easy to show.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f: (X,\mathcal{A}) \to (Y,\mathcal{B})$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$. Since the function $x \mapsto ax$ is continuous, what can you say about $f^{-1}(B)$?